# How do I add a second In App Subscription to Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am trying to use In App Subscriptions and have created and uploaded an APK to my Play Console. I had created two in app subscriptions but realized that they both had the same price as I was not thinking at the time I created them. I went to change the subscription price for one of them but was unable to even though it was inactive so I deleted the subscription.

I have been trying to create a second in app subscription but the following error message continues to display under Pricing: "You can’t modify the price and billing period of a subscription after it is activated.". I enter the title and description of the subscription, I enter the price I want for the subscription, but every time I go to save it says there is an error and the message in Pricing continues to display even though the subscription has not been activated.

I am also NOT using the same Product ID as the one I deleted. My app is set to ready for publish and I cannot see any error messages relating to the app.

I cannot see any help in Google Documentation, StackOverflow or any other area using Google search. Has anyone experienced this or know of a way to resolve this problem so I can have multiple subscriptions in my app?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the reason I was unable to add a second subscription was due to the minimum default price. The minimum price at this time is $0.99. My brain was not working and I was applying that minimum to the Australian price rather than the default price. All sorted now.

Hopefully this might help someone else.